# Groovy script set number of executors

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

Please help me, I'm trying to change the number of executors on jenkins. When I'm running this code, it works:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
jenkins.setNumExecutors(4)
jenkins.save()
```

When I use the next function:

```
void set_executors(int number) {

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
jenkins.setNumExecutors(number)
jenkins.save()
}
```

And running:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy /var/lib/jenkins/executor.groovy set_executors 4
```

I'm getting:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
Actions.set_executors() is applicable for argument types
(java.lang.String) values: [4]
Possible solutions: set_executors(int)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
```

Please help!

Comment: Shouldn't the line just be: `jenkins.setNumExecutors(number)`?

Comment: yes, it's wrong copy paste, i've fixed original message

Comment: Can you show the code where set_executors is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When run from the command line, groovy passes arguments as strings. Your *set_executors* function is being called with a String argument instead of an integer as the function expects. You need to modify your code to accept a String argument and convert it to an integer.

Comment: Thank you!
I have changed it to: void set_executors(String n)
and added conversion:
jenkins.setNumExecutors(Integer.parseInt(n))